# ¿Cómo convertir minutos a hora:minutos en Java Android?

Tags: java, android

Existe alguna función nativa para convertir minutos a formato hh:mm en Java?

partiendo de  `int minMovie = 120`

Debe devolver `02:00`

Comment: a partir de millisegundos? o cual formato inicial?

Comment: @Elenasys tengo un entero con los minutos que dura una pelicula

Comment: ok por ejemplo si dura 2 minutos tienes 120, o sea un formato en segundos? OK Acabo de ver tu actualización!

Comment: he agregado la respuesta a partir de tu requerimiento.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo mejor en este caso es utilizar [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) y aplicar un formato adecuado:

```
public String formatearMinutosAHoraMinuto(int minutos) {
    String formato = "%02d:%02d";
    long horasReales = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(minutos);
    long minutosReales = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(minutos) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(minutos));
    return String.format(formato, horasReales, minutosReales));
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
System.out.println(formatearMinutosAHoraMinuto(120));
System.out.println(formatearMinutosAHoraMinuto(90));
```

Salida:

```
02:00
01:30
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias

Answer (score 3):

A partir de un valor [`Date()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Date.html) :

```
Date myDate = new Date();
String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(myDate);
Log.i(TAG, "tiempo en HH:mm : " +  time);
```

A partir de millisegundos:

```
long   milliSeconds =  System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(myDate);
Log.i(TAG, "tiempo en HH:mm : " +  time);
```

---

**UPDATE**

Después de actualizar tu pregunta, esta sería la solución, a partir de un valor `int` en segundos, usando [**`TimeUnit`**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) :

```
int minMovie = 120
long tiempo = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(120);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(tiempo);
time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(myDate);
Log.i(TAG, "tiempo en HH:mm : " +  time);
```

En los 3 casos, tendrías una salida similar a:

```
tiempo en HH:mm : 11:12
```

Comment: y partiendo de que tienes en una variable int los minutos a convertir int minMovie=120

Comment: ok he agregado ese caso también, saludos.