# ¿Cómo convertir minutos en formato 0h 0min en Java Android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo total de minutos y me gustaría representar en formato 0h 0min, pero si la horas son 0, solo se muestre los minutos o viceversa:

```
30minutos -> 30min
60minutos -> 1h
65minutos -> 1h 5min
```

Seria adaptar la función de la respuesta [@Luiggi_Mendoza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9758/c%C3%B3mo-convertir-minutos-a-horaminutos-en-java-android)

```
public String formatearMinutosAHoraMinuto(int minutos) {
    String formato = "%02d:%02d";
    long horasReales = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(minutos);
    long minutosReales = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(minutos) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(minutos));
    return String.format(formato, horasReales, minutosReales));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta función puede ayudar para lo que necesita.

```
public String formatearMinutosAHoraMinuto(int t) {
     int hours = t / 60;
     int minutes = t % 60;
     return ((hours==0)? minutes+"min" : ((minutes!=0) ? hours +"h " + minutes + "min": hours+"h"));          
}
```

o si desea adaptar la función con `TimeUnit`  quedaría así :

```
public  String formatearMinutosAHoraMinuto(int minutos) {
  long horasReales = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(minutos);
  long minutosReales = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(minutos) - 
        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(minutos));
  return (((horasReales==0)? minutosReales+" min": 
        horasReales +"h" + ((minutosReales==0)? "": minutosReales+" min")));
}
```